# Jasmine Testing angular directive with [^form] dependency

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a directive, as explained e.g. here  http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/06/introduction-to-unit-test-directives/.

However, in my directive I use form, so I have this in my directive declaration object:

```
        return {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'E',
            require: ['^form'], // <- I have this !!
            scope: { //...
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {
            //...
            }
        };
```

as such, when I execute the usual prerequisite for my Jasmine test

```
element = '<mydirective/>';
element = $compile(element)(scope);
```

I am getting following dependency problem when trying to run karma / Jasmine test:

Error: [$compile:ctreq] **Controller 'form', required by directive 'mydirective', can't be found!**
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$compile/ctreq?p0=form&p1=mydirective

How this can be fixed?

Comment: Use `'<form><mydirective></mydirective></form>'`, and use `element.find('mydirective')` to find the actual directive element.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks! you can make it an asnwer actually. I think this bit is worth remembering

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
'<form><mydirective></mydirective></form>'
```

, and use `element.find('mydirective')` to find the actual directive element.